# Check if token still valid before request

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am using an index.js file to make api calls in a vue app. Is there a way to add a catch or a before each call to see if my token is still good and have the user redirected to login if it isnt?

```
import axios from 'axios'

const client = axios.create({
   baseURL : 'http://myapi.com/api/',
    json: true
})

export default {
    async execute(method, resource, data) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        return client({
          method,
          url: resource,
          data,
           crossdomain: true ,
          headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` }
        }).then(req => {
          return req.data
        })
      },

      getResponses() {
        return this.execute('get', 'GetResponses')
      },

      getAll(){
        return this.execute('get', 'GetAll')
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors), where you can pass a function to be called before each request:

```
const client = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://myapi.com/api/', json: true });

client.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if (isTokenGood(token)) {
    return config;
  } else {
    logout();
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried adding an interceptor in my router index.js file and that hasnt done a thing. What would that look like in my api/index.js file?

Comment: It would look just like the example I've shown. Of course, you'll also need to implement the `isTokenGood` and `logout` methods.

Comment: right, where would i place that isTokenGood method is where i am unsure. I tried adding it with my other call methods and get isTokenGood undefined. Where would i place that method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "call methods". You could define the `isTokenGood` function in the same scope that it's called in or in the main scope of that `index.js` file.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested i ended up going with an interceptor as per @thanksd 
My code index.js file in my api folder now looks like this

```
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '../router'

const client = axios.create({
   baseURL : 'http://myapi.com/api/',
    json: true
})

client.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response
}, function (error) {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    router.push('/Login')
    console.info('auth token expired')
    localStorage.clear()
    sessionStorage.clear()
  } else if (error.response.status === 403) {
    router.push('/Login')
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
})

export default {
    async execute(method, resource, data) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        return client({
          method,
          url: resource,
          data,
           crossdomain: true ,
          headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` }
        }).then(req => {
          return req.data
        })
      },

      getResponses() {
        return this.execute('get', 'GetResponses')
      },

      getAll(){
        return this.execute('get', 'GetAll')
      },
```